# Comparing the elements in lists

Tags: python, list, comparison

I am using the following script to compare the elements in two separate lists in Python3. If an element matches e.g. element `[0]` from list one matches element `[0]` from list two then the variable `c` is incremented by one. If the element does not match but the value is in the list then a different variable `d` is incremented.

I have put the code together but it is rather long and wanted to know if it could be condensed in some way.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,1,3,4]
c = 0
d = 0

if a[0] == b[0]:
    c += 1
elif a[0] == b[1] or a[0] == b[2] or a[0] == b[3]:
    d += 1

if a[1] == b[1]:
    c += 1
elif a[1] == b[0] or a[1] == b[2] or a[1] == b[3]:
    d += 1

if a[2] == b[2]:
    c += 1
elif a[2] == b[0] or a[2] == b[1] or a[2] == b[3]:
    d += 1

if a[3] == b[3]:
    c += 1
elif a[3] == b[0] or a[3] == b[1] or a[3] == b[2]:
    d += 1
```

Comment: Show your desired output, there is no doubt it can be condensed, it's `elif` or `else`, there's probably a dupe somewhere...

Comment: what's the desired results in case of reprtition?

Comment: the desired output is to compare each element for exact matches in value or if the same value is in the other list

Comment: so if `a=[1,2,3,4]` and `b=[1,1,2,1]`, the output must be `c=1` and `d=3`?

Comment: Yes that is correct Mehdi. The numbers in list a will change and the second list is a users input. The c and d variables are used to indicate the correct guesses made.

Comment: But usually in mastermind game when you are allowed to have repetition and if the correct answer is `1234` but you guess `1111` the indicators must be: `1/1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `elif` statement you can use `in`. Let's look an example:

I have this list: `a = [1, 2, 3]`. `0 in a`returns `False` but `1 in a` returns `True`.

So, your code will look like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,1,3,4]
c = 0
d = 0

if a[0] == b[0]:
    c += 1
elif a[0] in b:
    d += 1

if a[1] == b[1]:
    c += 1
elif a[1] in b:
    d += 1

if a[2] == b[2]:
    c += 1
elif a[2] in b:
    d += 1

if a[3] == b[3]:
    c += 1
elif a[3] in b:
    d += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,1,3,4]

match = [a[i] == b[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] in b]
c = sum(match)
d = len(match)-c
```

In this code `match` consists of boolean values, for matchings locations per members in the intersection of `a` and `b`.

This code will perform similarly to what was asked in the question. However, if the intention is to use it like mastermind game, this won't work. For example, if `a=[1,2,3,4]` and `b=[4,4,4,4]` the matching indicator must be: `1/1`. The following code would do:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [4,4,4,4]

c = sum([a[i] == b[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] in b])
d = sum([min(b.count(item), a.count(item)) for item in set(a)]) - c
```

Similar to the first guess in following game screenshot:

[image: masetermind example]

Comment: The code is too compressed I put this description to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this.

```
c = [e[0]==e[1] for e in [*zip(a,b)]].count(True)
d = [e in b for e in a].count(True) - c
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be condensed by using a `for`-loop and you can also make it more performant by doing the `elseif` (in Python this is called `elif`) check on a `set`.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,1,3,4]
c = 0
d = 0

b_set = set(b)
for item_from_a, item_from_b in zip(a, b):
    if item_from_a == item_from_b:
        c += 1
    elif item_from_a in b_set:
        d += 1
```

With `zip` one iterates over both lists at once, so it will in the first iteration access the first element from `a` and `b` (i.e. `1` and `2`) in the second iteration it will access the second element from both lists (`2` and `1`) and so on. You could also write it as loop over the indices (it's not as "clean" as using `zip` but maybe easier to understand):

```
for idx in range(len(a)):
    item_from_a = a[idx]
    item_from_b = b[idx]
    if item_from_a == item_from_b:
        c += 1
    elif item_from_a in b_set:
        d += 1
```

The loop body itself should be fairly straightforward but please leave a comment if some part needs more explanation.

Comment: I havent used the zip function before. if you could please provide more info or an example it would be mucha appreciatted,

Comment: @zeeman Look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip. Zip is defintely one of the functions mostly used in Python.

Comment: @zeeman `zip` is just a tool to iterate over multiple containers at once. It avoids having to loop over indices or calling `next` manually. There's a great answer (including examples) in this [Q+A on "How can I iterate through two lists in parallel?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)